# PrimeNG - Organization chart

Tags: angular, frontend, primeng

I'm trying to implement an organization chart from [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/#/organizationchart). I managed to copy/paste the basic chart. But I want to use the advanced one. So I checked out the Source section.

What I did:
1) Copied the relevant HTML part of the advanced case into my HTML holder in my Angular component
2) Added the "styles" to my "app.component.ts". I commented out the standard variable: "styleUrls"
3) Copied in the relevant data for the class

It just shows a blank page. I tried to narrow down the problem and it seems to stem from  parts in the HTML code:

[image]
Because when I comment it out, I get the tree but without the much of the intended parts from PrimeNG, which noteably are also weirdly not expanded correct:

[image]

Has anyone an idea why it doesn't work for me? Here is my complete code from the **app.component.ts** section:

```
import { Component, OnInit, ViewEncapsulation } from '@angular/core';
import { TreeNode, Message } from 'primeng/api';


@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  // styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
  styles: [`
  .company.ui-organizationchart .ui-organizationchart-node-content.ui-person {
      padding: 0;
      border: 0 none;
  }

  .node-header,.node-content {
      padding: .5em .7em;
  }

  .node-header {
      background-color: #495ebb;
      color: #ffffff;
  }

  .node-content {
      text-align: center;
      border: 1px solid #495ebb;
  }

  .node-content img {
      border-radius: 50%;
  }

  .department-cfo {
      background-color: #7247bc;
      color: #ffffff;
  }

  .department-coo {
      background-color: #a534b6;
      color: #ffffff;
  }

  .department-cto {
      background-color: #e9286f;
      color: #ffffff;
  }

  .ui-person .ui-node-toggler {
      color: #495ebb !important;
  }

  .department-cto .ui-node-toggler {
      color: #8a0a39 !important;
  }
`],
encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None
})

export class AppComponent implements OnInit{
  title = 'app';
  data: TreeNode[];

  selectedNode: TreeNode;

  messages: Message[];

  ngOnInit() {
      this.data = [{
          label: 'CEO',
          type: 'person',
          styleClass: 'ui-person',
          expanded: true,
          data: {name:'Walter White', 'avatar': 'walter.jpg'},
          children: [
              {
                  label: 'CFO',
                  type: 'person',
                  styleClass: 'ui-person',
                  expanded: true,
                  data: {name:'Saul Goodman', 'avatar': 'saul.jpg'},
                  children:[{
                      label: 'Tax',
                      styleClass: 'department-cfo'
                  },
                  {
                      label: 'Legal',
                      styleClass: 'department-cfo'
                  }],
              },
              {
                  label: 'COO',
                  type: 'person',
                  styleClass: 'ui-person',
                  expanded: true,
                  data: {name:'Mike E.', 'avatar': 'mike.jpg'},
                  children:[{
                      label: 'Operations',
                      styleClass: 'department-coo'
                  }]
              },
              {
                  label: 'CTO',
                  type: 'person',
                  styleClass: 'ui-person',
                  expanded: true,
                  data: {name:'Jesse Pinkman', 'avatar': 'jesse.jpg'},
                  children:[{
                      label: 'Development',
                      styleClass: 'department-cto',
                      expanded: true,
                      children:[{
                          label: 'Analysis',
                          styleClass: 'department-cto'
                      },
                      {
                          label: 'Front End',
                          styleClass: 'department-cto'
                      },
                      {
                          label: 'Back End',
                          styleClass: 'department-cto'
                      }]
                  },
                  {
                      label: 'QA',
                      styleClass: 'department-cto'
                  },
                  {
                      label: 'R&D',
                      styleClass: 'department-cto'
                  }]
              }
          ]
      }];
  }

  onNodeSelect(event) {
      this.messages = [{severity: 'success', summary: 'Node Selected', detail: event.node.label}];
  }
}
```

And here is from the **HTML**:

```
<p-organizationChart [value]="data" selectionMode="single" [(selection)]="selectedNode" (onNodeSelect)="onNodeSelect($event)"styleClass="company">
  <ng-template let-node pTemplate="person">
    <div class="node-header ui-corner-top">{node.label}</div>
    <div class="node-content">
        <img src="./src/app/{node.data.avatar}" width="32">
        <div>{node.data.name}</div>
    </div>
</ng-template>
<ng-template let-node pTemplate="department">
  {node.label}
</ng-template>

</p-organizationChart>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please provide everything we need to understand the question from the post itself. Link only to relevant resources but don't ask people to download or visit external websites to understand your problem. Share what you've tried and what the errors are.

Comment: @cgTag Thanks! I will update my question to become more detailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Todays lesson:

1. Use inspect and see if there are any error messages. I had to install and import BrowserAnimationsModule from @angular/animations
2. For solving the other error messages I found revolved around basic Angular syntax. Luckily, I watched a crash course video about Angular syntax before lunch so I spotted the problem after 15 minutes of intensive search why the js crashed in the HTML. As you can see, PrimeNG doesn't write out automatically two brackets **"{{"** & **"}}"**. After adding these, then my problem was solved and I retrieved back into the darkness of my programming dungeon.

Hope it helps some beginner with similar problems!